# MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 while connecting from node:alpine to mongo in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have following `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  mongodb:
    name: mongodb
    driver: bridge
  host:
    name: host
    driver: host

services:
  nodejs-server:  
    networks:
      - mongodb
      - host
    build:
      context: ./api
      network: host
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    container_name: node-api
    volumes:
       - ./api:/usr/src/app/api
       - /usr/src/app/api/node_modules

mongodb:
    image: mongo
    networks:
      mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: Demo
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

and `index.js` file in `Express` server

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const mongoDB = 'mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017';
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoDB);
```

```
app.get('/mongo', async (req, res) => {

    console.log('connecting...');
    await mongoClient.connect();
    console.log('connected...');
    const database = mongoClient.db('insertDB');
    const haiku = database.collection('haiku');
});
```

When I run the app, it stucks on `await mongoClient.connect();` and throws following exception:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

So when log in to `docker container` in `nodejs-server` if I run `ping`:

```
/usr/src/app/api # ping mongodb
PING mongodb (172.21.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.199 ms
```

So I am not sure why driver cannot connect? Would it be port problem or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have your node-api container inside the "host" network and another network. I am not exactly sure what your docker-compose file will produce, but I assume it puts the node-api into the host network. The host network in docker is a special network as it disables network encapsulation. This means there is no network namespace created for the container and it can't connect to other docker networks.

What you need to do is either put node-api inside only the mongodb network or change your monogdb connection string to `mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017` as port 27017 on your host should be mapped to the correct port inside the mongodb container.

Comment: After I changed the connection string to `mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017` it worked like a charm <3

Comment: I'd recommend deleting _all_ of the `networks:` blocks in the file instead.  Both containers will be on a Compose-provided network named `default` and you should be able to use `mongodb` as a host name as in the question.  It's pretty unusual to actually need host networking.

Comment: I had an  issue with `npm i` without `host` networking. If I don't have it, it was not able to install node packages (step was hanging forever). I think it is `Ubuntu` specific issue because I don't remember I needed it on Windows or Mac. @DavidMaze